# Enabling line for block of code in the Adobe Brackets

Tags: line, highlight, adobe-brackets

[image: Enabling line for block of code in the Adobe Brackets]

I'm using the Adobe Brackets and want to activate a line for my block of code within braces, as indicated in the picture above.

Comment: seems like a question about the development environment you are working in (?) - if so, it could help to specify the programming language & software and use those tags

Comment: I'm using a program the name is "Brackets"  and i don't know how to activate that line in the picture, do you know how?

Comment: Ah I see Brackets _is_ the IDE.  I'll edit and re-tag the question; as stated in the [brackets] tag: "DO NOT USE THIS for the IDE, use [adobe-brackets] instead."

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Indent Guides](https://github.com/lkcampbell/brackets-indent-guides) Extension.
If I understand your question correctly, it should do what you want.